# query IE9 problems with hide/show

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, refresh, reload

I have a site:

http://www.leadcomm.net/cost-estimate/

The script is long so I dont know if it can be posted here. You can view if you view source at the page.

the script works for FFX, Chrome, and IE8. IE9 has an issue that If you go into the page the jquery wont load or work at all unless you refresh the page. Then it works.

If I click "Cost Estimate" on the nav bar from any other page, The jquery wont load. After Refreshing, it will work.

I've been browsing threads similar and it sounds like an undefined variable but I looked at everything. I've been at it for the past 8 hours. Any input on where to look would be awesome. I hate Internet Explorer.

Comment: Im new at jquery. Would using apostrophes instead of quotation marks or vice versa be an issue. I mixed and matched them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try including the $(document).ready inside the following:

```
window.onload = (function () {

});
```

Comment: like this?   window.onload = (function ($j(document).ready) {

Comment: sorry. I just figured out what you meant.

Comment: This makes no sense.  `$j(document).ready` already waits for the DOM to be ready.   Why in the world would you use `$j(document).ready` inside a `window.onload`.  If you want to wait for all images to be loaded, then use just the `window.onload`.  If you only need to wait for the DOM to be ready, then just use the `$j(document).ready`.

Comment: I hate internet explorer but you, sir are godly. Thanks! I'm learning as I go and I've went through every CSS and ID to make sure it wasnt a missing class or div. Thanks a million! 8 hours...

Comment: Great to hear that worked! This is an odd issue with IE9. Real browsers don't need this.  Got this from the jquery documentation.

Comment: I never would have guess it either but for some reason it worked. Hats off to ya.